# Custom Rlocus Plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I need to create a custom rlocus plot in the app designer which does not support the native rlocus command.

I used `[r,k] = rlocus(sys)` and grabbed the r and k vectors and used pzmap poles and zeros to plot up a custom `rlocus` plot.

However, I would like to plot the current gain of my system on the rlocus plot.  Neither `dcgain(sys)` nor `[z,g]=zero(sys)` nor `[a,b,k]=zpkdata(sys)` seem to be giving me accurate answers, except for the most simple of systems.

Any suggestions on how I can get this done?  Thanks!